# What's the difference between using a heading tag and a large font in a <p> tag?

Tags: html

What's the difference between using a heading tag like h1, h6 and a large font in a `<p>` tag?

I am interested in how it would affect not only the readability of the code but about other issues which led to the creation of heading tags instead of using larger font in a `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 7):

> What's the difference between using a heading tag and a large font in a `<p>` tag?

[Semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML).

Answer (score 7):

Functionally, nothing.  Semantically, everything.  `<p>` describes a paragraph, and `<h*>` describe headings.  If your HTML is to be consumed, it makes a big difference.  Take a look at [the HTML outliner](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/) to see how search engines / headless browsers / CSS-free browsers will interpret `<p>` vs. `<h*>` tags and how it lays out your document.

Answer (score 2):

This will affect readability not only for other devs or readers but it mostly matters for search engines. You want to give a semantic meaning to your code. Bring more weight to word that matter more.
When a search engine spider crawls your site, it is easier to identify what your content is about. It's a good practice for SEO.